# WPF - MVVM: ComboBox value after SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

I am new to C# and MVVM, and I've spent all day trying to get the value of a `ComboBox` to my ViewModel on `SelectionChanged`. I have managed to figure it out using either `CallMethodAction` or `InvokeCommandAction` with the resources:

- `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`
- `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll`

My problem is that both these methods return the value of the `ComboBox` before it has changed. Could anyone explain how to get the value *after* the change?

I have spent hours searching through SO and Google for a solution, so I wonder if others are too. Any advice will be appreciated!

My code is below:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SelectionChange.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:si="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SelectionChange"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="SelectBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="0">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <si:CallMethodAction MethodName="SelectionChanged" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                    <!--<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SelectBox, Path=Text}" />-->
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
namespace SelectionChange
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            SelectionChangedCommand = new SelectionChangedCommand();
        }

        public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox SelectBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("Called SelectionChanged: " + SelectBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

**SelectionChangedCommand.cs**

```
namespace SelectionChange
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public class SelectionChangedCommand : ICommand
    {
        public SelectionChangedCommand()
        {
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Executed SelectionChangedCommand: " + parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: My Solution**

It turns out I didn't understand `Binding` well enough and instead was trying to implement something simple in a rather complicated way! Instead of using dependencies, I have now achieved what I needed using regular bindings. As an example, I've bound a `TextBox` to the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox`, which gets updated using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

[image: MainWindow.xaml Screenshot]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SelectionChange.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SelectionChange"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
        </ComboBox>

        <!-- TextBox to display the ComboBox's SelectedIndex -->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedIndex}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
namespace SelectionChange
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {   
        }

        // Property to store / retrieve ComboBox's SelectedIndex
        private int _SelectedIndex;
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

        // Property to bind to ComboBox's SelectedItem
        private ComboBoxItem _SelectedItem;
        public ComboBoxItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _SelectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedItem = value;

                // SelectedItem's Content
                string Content = (string)value.Content;

                // SelectedItem's parent (i.e. the ComboBox)
                ComboBox SelectBox = (ComboBox)value.Parent;

                // ComboBox's SelectedIndex
                int Index = SelectBox.SelectedIndex;

                // Store the SelectedIndex in the property
                SelectedIndex = Index;

                // Raise PropertyChanged with the name of the stored property
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }

        // INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765362/mvvm-combobox-binding

Comment: I will just drop an idea for you. How about you bind SelectedItems property to a property in your ViewModel with binding mode TwoWay? No need to listen to SelectionChanged event or creating commands. Whenever the SelectedItems value gets changed you will get notified inside the setter of your property in ViewModel. Try it out.

Comment: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PropertyWhichHasList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"                SelectedItem="{Binding PropertyWhichHasSelectedItem}"
      </ComboBox>. Try something like this .

Comment: Thanks to all 3 suggestions! They helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not do it the simpler way

```
<ComboBox MaxHeight="25" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In your ViewModel declare the combo box items and use a property "Source" to return it to the view

```
List<string> _source = new List<string>{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
public List<string> Source 
{ 
    get { return _source; } 
}
```

Then define one property which holds the selected item

```
string _theSelectedItem = null;
public string TheSelectedItem 
{ 
    get { return _theSelectedItem; } 
    set { _theSelectedItem = value; } // NotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Also don't forget to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface while setting the _source

Comment: This is closest to what I ended up with, and I guess, depending on what you wanted to do with the ComboBox, could be the solution (for someone else). @aks81, Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get notified when your current item changes, why not use tools that are already part of WPF instead of all these dependencies.

First get the underlying view to your collection and use the CurrentChanged event on it.

```
ComboBoxList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ComboBoxList);
view.MoveCurrentTo(ComboBoxList[0]);
view.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBoxCurrentChanged);
```

In your xaml you just bind your collection and set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true.

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxList}"/>
```