# PropertyChangedCallback not firing when respective property bound to ScrollBar

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, propertychanged, data-binding

I have a rather simple UserControl which I would like to extend with the DependencyProperty. The relevant code of the control is as follows:

```
    public partial class CompassControl : UserControl
    {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(Double), typeof(CompassControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(  0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAngleChanged)));

    private static void OnAngleChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
        {
        ((CompassControl)target).SetImageAngle((Double)e.NewValue);
        }

    public CompassControl( )
        {
        InitializeComponent( );
        }

    public Double Angle
        {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
        }
```

This control is being used on a simple form; the relevant XAML as follows:

```
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                       TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12"          
                       Padding="0,4,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Height="22" Width="60" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=scrollBarAngle, Path=Value}">
            </TextBlock>

            <ScrollBar DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="scrollBarAngle" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                       Height="22" Margin="10,0"
                       Maximum="360.0" Minimum="0.0" SmallChange="1.0" Value="0.0"
                       ValueChanged="scrollBarAngle_ValueChanged" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>

    <ctl:CompassControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="compassControl" 
                        Margin="5" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                        Angle="{Binding ElementName=scrollBarAngle, Path=Value}"
                        />

</DockPanel>
```

The "Text" property of the TextBox and the "Angle" property of my control are bound to the "Value" property of the ScrollBar using the following binding:

```
"{Binding ElementName=scrollBarAngle, Path=Value}"
```

When I scroll the ScrollBar, the Text field is updated as expected, but the Angle  does not change - the OnAngleChanged callback is not being called!

However if I directly change the Angle property in the ScrollBar's ValueChanged event everything works fine - the property got changed and the respective callback fired:

```
        private void scrollBarAngle_ValueChanged( object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e )
        {
        compassControl.Angle = e.NewValue;
        }
```

Please help resolve this issue!

Thank you,
--Alex

Comment: you can use Triggers for it please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620581/wpf-mvvm-combobox-value-after-selectionchanged

Comment: Your code does actually work. I've added the `SetImageAngle` method with test output and it is called as expected. The problem can't be reproduced with the code you're showing here.

Comment: Clemens, did you use my sample code with or without the event method    <code>scrollBarAngle_ValueChanged(...)<code>? If I use it and force update on the compassControl.Angle everything works fine. If I comment out this line, no updates are propagated to compassControl. I can upload the whole project for your review - it is rather small.

Answer (score -1):

My apologies - the problem was not in the code, but in the environment! I had several copies of VS2013 open, the project was open in two of them. Anyway, after reading Clemens comment indicating that my problem is not reproducible, I closed all instances of VS, then started the fresh instance, opened the project - and everything worked fine!

Thank you!